# Last Modified Date across multiple servers

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I am working on improving browser caching.  I have a client with multiple servers.  When a request is made the server will cache the response.  I have been only using the max-age setting to set browser cache, but I see that google says you need to also supply max-age and last-modified header for it to be correctly cached on all browsers.

The situation I have is that the Last-Modified date could be different on the multiple servers but the content is the same.  If I use the last mod date and the browser sees that the other server has a different one, will it re-download the file even though the max-age hasn't been hit?